# postgresql: print transactions from WAL logs

Tags: postgresql, logging, wal

I want to know if there is a way to read the transactions from WAL logs in a simpler way. I want the transactions not the binary data . I used pg_xlogdump but I have no idea how to get the transactions from the result which looked like this

```
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    64, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D3C8, prev 0/0172D380, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 284, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/3455 blk 1
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):      3/   171, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D408, prev 0/0172D3C8, desc: INSERT off 35, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/1249 blk 44
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    64, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D4B8, prev 0/0172D408, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 91, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2658 blk 13
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    64, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D4F8, prev 0/0172D4B8, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 309, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2659 blk 8
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):      3/   193, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D538, prev 0/0172D4F8, desc: INSERT off 25, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2610 blk 2
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    64, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D600, prev 0/0172D538, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 121, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2678 blk 1
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    64, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D640, prev 0/0172D600, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 122, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2679 blk 1
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):      3/  1786, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172D680, prev 0/0172D640, desc: INSERT off 3, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2606 blk 0 FPW
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/   209, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172DD80, prev 0/0172D680, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 2, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2664 blk 1 FPW
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/   153, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172DE58, prev 0/0172DD80, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 3, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2665 blk 1 FPW
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/   153, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172DEF8, prev 0/0172DE58, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 1, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2666 blk 1 FPW
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/   153, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172DF98, prev 0/0172DEF8, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 3, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2667 blk 1 FPW
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):      3/    80, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172E050, prev 0/0172DF98, desc: INSERT off 79, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2608 blk 53
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    72, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172E0A0, prev 0/0172E050, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 235, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2673 blk 38
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    72, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172E0E8, prev 0/0172E0A0, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 113, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2674 blk 44
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):      3/    80, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172E130, prev 0/0172E0E8, desc: INSERT off 80, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2608 blk 53
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    72, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172E180, prev 0/0172E130, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 231, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2673 blk 38
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):      2/    72, tx:        659, lsn: 0/0172E1C8, prev 0/0172E180, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 109, blkref #0: rel 1663/12411/2674 blk 23
```

Actually I want the transactions in SQL. If I get to know what every transaction is and the values of the fields that will be enough.

Comment: You can't recover SQL from raw WAL logs; that's why they invented [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logicaldecoding-example.html)

Comment: Is there a way to get what transaction happened with each transaction ID along with the fields.?? I can convert that to SQL myself.@NickBarnes

Answer (score 4):

There is not enough information in the WAL files to get the SQL statements that caused the modifications.

Basically, the first WAL entry in your sample translates to:
*In block 1 of file `1663/12411/3455`,insert an index entry at offset 284.*
The WAL entry also contains the raw data to write there, but `pg_xlogdump` doesn't show them.

So all I can see from this WAL is that something inserted data into a table that had an index on it, and the table was probably small.
This information is enough to recover the changes to the data files, but there is no way ro reconstruct the SQL statement from it.

In short, the WAL contains the *physical* changes to the database, not the *logical* ones.